# Get the cart details from the order id in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How we can get the complete cart details from the order id in woocommerce including the totals and subtotals etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
?>
```

Comment: Not sure how this could be the accepted answer, as I know `$woocommerce->cart->get_cart()` will return the cart from the "current" session, but the question is about how to get the details (including totals and items) for exist (old) order!

Answer (score 2):

You can get order's cart details from the order object.

if you only have the `id`, you can get `$order` object like this:

```
// Get $order object from order ID
  
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

to get order's details:

```
if ( $order ) {

    // Get Order Totals $0.00
    $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    $order->get_cart_tax();
    $order->get_currency();
    $order->get_discount_tax();
    $order->get_discount_to_display();
    $order->get_discount_total();
    // etc.
    // etc.

    // Get and Loop Over Order Items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
       $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
       $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
       // etc.
       // etc.
    }
}
```

You can refer to this link for more details:
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: This actually answers the question, which was not 'how to get the current order' but  'how to get the order details from the id'. THIS should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
<?php

WC()->cart->get_cart();
```